# load bash comands from file one per line and execute them for each file in a directory

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed, for

I'm trying to write a bash queue which will be able to load command sets from a file and then execute each over a set of files.
The prepared file should serve as a template for execution in manual bash queues

prepared file `sed.sh`:
<sub>(I have also comments in the file but i don't know how to add them here)</sub>

```
sed -e 's,something_complex_long,something_even_longer,'
sed -e 's,other_complex_long_thing,something_so_much_longer,'
sed -e 's,another_long_stuff,something_hell_long,'
```

and there is  directory with set of quite huge files with generic names such as `aa` `ab` `ac` etc. <sub>(sliced down even bigger file using split)</sub>

So I tried:

```
sedie=\`grep -v -e '^#' ../../sed.sh\`
for i in *
do
  for b in $sedie
  do
    cat $i | $b > ${i}.new
    mv ${i}.new $i
  done
done
```

Which of course totally failed, since the second `for` breaks up statements in `$sedie` by spaces.

Then I tried to go along using `IFS` as I have found somewhere but still not much progress. Then I thought I should load the commands in some kind of array to help differentiate what I want ... maybe change `sed.sh` like `arr=("sed " "sed " "sed ")` and then source `sed.sh` and then `for b in ${arr[*]}`?

Anybody please know how to deal with this in an elegant way (e.g., reusable) manually ?

My `IFS` try was rather cumbersome and didn't work anyway... `$b` became a single statement including the spaces and all and there were no such command

```
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
sedie=\`grep -v -e '^#' ../../sed.sh\`
for i in *
do
  for b in $sedie
  do
    echo cat $i \| $($b) \> ${i}.new
    echo mv ${i}.new $i
  done
done
IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

which was not elegant at all.

#### UPDATE #1

Using this Q: [extract file contents into array using bash scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20294918/extract-file-contents-into-array-using-bash-scripting)
and this one: [How to execute command stored in a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668640/how-to-execute-command-stored-in-a-variable), now I'm able to ..

```
$ cat > myfile 
aaaaaaaa
aaaaaaa
aaaaaa
aaaa
aa
aaaa

$ cat sed.sh 
sed -e 's/a/b/g'
sed -e 's/b/c/g'
sed -e 's/c/f/g'

$ declare -a pole
$ readarray pole < sed.sh
$ for ((i=0;i<${#pole[@]};i++));do \
    eval ${pole[i]} xfile > xfile.b; mv xfile.b xfile; done; 

$ cat xfile
ffffffff
fffffff
ffffff
ffff
ff
ffff
```

Which is almost what I needed. So my question is basically two:

> how to read file into array?

and

> how to execute command in variable?

Comment: Rather than invoking sed repeatedly in a loop, why not just put the sed *expressions* in a file and apply them to each file using `sed -f script-file <yourfiles>`?

Comment: @sudo - please do not use the answer section for follow up information - use the edit button below your Q to refine it as new information becomes available.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly what you are after but since it looks like you are using sed the you could create a file sed.cmd with just the sed commands you want to execute.

```
s,something_complex_long,something_even_longer,
s,other_complex_long_thing,something_so_much_longer,
s,another_long_stuff,something_hell_long,
```

I used the following in my test sed.cmd

```
s/dog/cat
```

Then create a script that reads those commands into an array and call sed passing in those commands

```
array=()

# Read the file in parameter and fill the array named "array"
getArray() {
    i=0
    while read line # Read a line
    do
        array[i]=$line # Put it into the array
        i=$(($i + 1))
    done < $1
}

getArray "sed.cmd"

for cmd in "${array[@]}"
do
    ls -1 | while read line 
do 
    cat $line | sed -e $cmd > ${line}.new
    mv ${line}.new $line
done
done
```

You will probably want to change the ls command to order the files but the above seems to meet your requirements.